# Python - exec(open('file.py').read()) reports error - No such file or directory. 'file.py'

Tags: python, exec, python-3.3

I'm just starting Python (3.3) on Windows 7, and the book I've been using (*Learning Python, by Mark Lutz*) says I can also run Python modules by using the **exec(...)** function. This is the code the author presents:

```
>>> exec(open('script2.py').read())
```

The error this code shows is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'script2.py'
```

To emphasise, I do have the *PYTHONPATH* variable set, and therefore the **import** function works properly: it doesn't show any error messages after *importing* a module.

I have provided the screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzDLE.png

To prove that the file imports normally, I will take a screenshot when *importing* that file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLiH4.png

Even though I don't believe there is something wrong with the Pathway, but with the function itself... Help!

Comment: Do you actually have a `script2.py` in the working directory?

Comment: compare the output of: import sys; print(sys.path) for both cases. You might not be in the folder you think you are

Comment: Not sure what to compare, I can normally import sys and script2.py. Yes, I do have a "script2.py" in the working directory which is shown in the second picture. (Can you see the pictures, do I have to upload to somewhere else?)

Comment: What is the location of script2.py?

Comment: No, just because you can import it (its somewhere in the maze of python import paths) doesn't mean its in the local directory. Exit python and do a `dir`.

Comment: C:\User\Matko\Desktop\Python

Comment: I've set a Pythonpath variable so it's included when searched for it.

Comment: If it's normally imported, why isn't it normaly exec-uted?

Comment: There's your problem. Its not in the current working directory. `open` does not search the python paths.

Comment: What is my current working directory then? C:\Python33 ?/And how to change it then?

Comment: C:\Users\Matko. Just exit python and the prompt will tell you. Or use python itself `import os;os.getcwd()`. You can change it with os.chdir() or add more info to the path 'Desktop\\script2.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open('xyz') does not search the various python import paths. If you give a relative path name, it starts with the current working directory, appends your path and looks there. If you give an absolute path, it ignores the current directory.